# react-navigation: access stateChange event of nested navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to add a state change event to a nested navigator.

Usually I would define it like this:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Next: {
        screen: NextNavigator,
    },

})
```

but I need something like this:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Next: {
        screen: (props)=>{ return <NextNavigator {...props}/> },
    },

})
```

where the screen object is a function.

The problem is I have no idea what signature `screen` as a function has, and how to pass it to the navigator

I'm getting close with something like this:

```
            screen: (props, state)=>{ return <NextNavigator {...props} state /> },
```

But it's still not correct.

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

## Use Params

Use `setParams`, `getParam` for changing state in components wrapped by navigatior.

A Component (Set changing value)

```js
const name = this.props.navigation.setParams({ name: this.state.name, age: this.state.age });
```

B Component (Get value)

```js
const name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'DefaultValue');
const age = this.props.navigation.getParam('age' 0);
```

`setParams` is a trigger to run `getParam` in other components is wrapped navigation.

## Extend Navigator

You can extend the component created by `Naivgator` as below. [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#extending-navigators)

```
const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ ... });

class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = MyStack.router;
  state = {
    a: 'b',    
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return <MyStack {...this.state, ...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Or it is able to use functional component instead.

```
const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ ... });

CustomNavigator = (props) => {
  return <MyStack {...props} />
}

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Next: {
        screen: (props) => { return <MyStack {...props} /> },
    },
    Third: CustomNavigator,
})

And do not forget import `React` to use functional component.
```

Comment: I am doing that, but when I navigate between the two tabs, when one of the tabs updates params, when you go back to the other tab, the change is not respected. I need a way of knowing that the tabs have been switched so that I can re-render, re-grab the params that have been set by the other tab. So, I want access to `onNavigationStateChange` so that I can respond to the tab change. Is there another way?

Comment: @ChristopherReid Navigation's param  trigger `render()` as `setState` . I am not sure how you use `getPram` in your component, but it is the right way to control states in component wrapped navigation.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to do something after change tab, use navigation's lifecycle methods as didFocus, willBlur and so on. [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

Comment: Thank you, that should help me with my current issue. But I am still curious how one would define a navigator as a function that returns the navigator, and not just the navigator itself.

Comment: @ChristopherReid You can. I extended my answer and I think your first way is almost right. I did not test your code and mine yet. So it would be something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want @JeffGuKang to answer, you can declare and use global variables and functions.

```js
let NICKNAME = '';


function setNickName(data) {
  NICKNAME = data;
}

function getNickName() {
  return NICKNAME;
}

export { setNickName,getNickName }
...
//set data
import { setNickName} from './globalpath';

setNickName(data)
....
//get data
import { getNickName} from './globalpath';

getNickName()
```

Comment: Global variable cannot trigger render as props.

Comment: @JeffGuKang Is there a reason to send it as a prop? You can import the data through import.

Comment: I think questioner want to treat variables as state. So, your way can be use with `Context`.

Comment: Since the questioner is to obtain variables from the nested stack, my method may be more convenient to obtain data.